# Nicely printing/showing a binary tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree, show

I have a tree data type:

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a
```

...and I need to make it an instance of `Show`, without using `deriving`. I have found that nicely displaying a little branch with two leaves is easy:

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
   show (Leaf x) = show x
   show (Branch val l r) = " " ++ show val ++ "\n" ++ show l ++ "  " ++ show r
```

But how can I extend a nice structure to a tree of arbitrary size? It seems like determining the spacing would require me to know just how many leaves will be at the very bottom (or maybe just how many leaves there are in total) so that I can allocate all the space I need there and just work 'up.' I would probably need to call a size function. I can see this being workable, but is that making it harder than it is?

Comment: You are looking for a text layout library/pretty printer. Have a look at [`wl-pprint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint) and similar libraries.

Comment: Also relevant: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty-show

Comment: So, recommended no-go on actually calculating it out?

Comment: Why would you actually want to do the calculations yourself if libraries are available?

Comment: I think I might actually have to for this assignment, but I think I'll check with the prof. And it would be a fun challenge either way!

Comment: You should probably add the `homework` tag, since this seems to be coursework.

Comment: @JohnL: The `homework` tag [has been deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: I thought only code can be deprecated :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might study the [`drawTree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/src/Data.Tree.html#drawTree) function in the base [`Data.Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/src/Data-Tree.html) module.  Just shamelessly importing it would give you something like this:

```
import Data.Tree hiding (Tree )
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) 
              | Leaf a deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

toDataTree (Leaf a) = Node a []
toDataTree (Branch b cs ds) = Node b [toDataTree cs, toDataTree ds]

d = Branch "1" (Branch "11" (Leaf "111") (Leaf "112")) 
               (Branch "12" (Leaf "121") (Leaf "122"))

e = toDataTree d
f = putStrLn $ drawTree e

{-
*Main> f
1
|
+- 11
|  |
|  +- 111
|  |
|  `- 112
|
`- 12
   |
   +- 121
   |
   `- 122
-}
```

Answer (score 15):

Using applicative's link to the `Data.Tree` source I came up with this. I wanted to write my own so I could learn more about it. The `drawTree` method in the source is generalized to work with nodes with multiple children; mine is just for binary trees.

Note: my tree definition is a little different than the OP's. I don't quite understand what the `a` type parameter is used for, but the approach should still be the same

```
data Tree a
    = Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)
    | Leaf

prettyprint (Leaf)
    = "Empty root."
-- unlines concats a list with newlines
prettyprint (Branch left node right) = unlines (prettyprint_helper (Branch left node right n h))

prettyprint_helper (Branch left node right)
    = (show node) : (prettyprint_subtree left right)
        where
            prettyprint_subtree left right =
                ((pad "+- " "|  ") (prettyprint_helper right))
                    ++ ((pad "`- " "   ") (prettyprint_helper left))
            pad first rest = zipWith (++) (first : repeat rest)
prettyprint_helper (Leaf)
    = []
```

Which produces a tree like

```
4
+- 8
|  +- 9
|  |  +- 10
|  `- 6
|     +- 7
|     `- 5
`- 2
   +- 3
   `- 1
```

---

I just wanted to explain how the `pad` function works, since that was the hardest for me to follow (called `shift` in the source).

Firstly, [`zipWith`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zipWith_f.html) applies a function (first argument) to "join" two lists. `zipWith (+) [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]` return `[5, 7, 9]`. It stops when one of the lists is empty. `zipWith` applied to only one list returns a function that can be applied to zip a second list (I believe this is known as [function currying](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying)). Here's a simpler version of the `pad` function:

```
> let pad = zipWith (++) (repeat "   ")
> :type pad
pad :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
> pad ["1", "2", "3"]
["   1", "   2", "   3"]
```

Notice:
1. One of the lists is infinite (`repeat "   "`), but it zipping stops when one of the lists is empty
2. `zipWith` only takes a function and a list. `pad` is then a function that takes a list of list of chars/strings and returns the zipped list of list of chars/strings. So you apply `pad` on a single list to zip it up with the first one

Now let's look at

```
prettyprint_subtree left right =
    ((pad "+- " "|  ") (prettyprint_helper left))
        ++ ((pad "`- " "   ") (prettyprint_helper right))
```

`(pad "+- " "|  ")` creates an infinite list like `["+- ", "|  ", "|  ", "|  ", ...]`. `(prettyprint_helper right)` builds the list of lines that represents the subtree on the right, starting with the right's root node. But that whole tree needs to be shifted to the right; we do that by zipping it with the padding. We use an infinite list because we don't know how large the subtree is; there will always be enough `"|  "`s to pad the extra lines (this also works because of lazy evaluation). Note that the first line; i.e. the subtree-root-node, is padded with `"+- "` instead, the "notation" for a right node.

The left side is virtually the same. The notation for a left node is `` "`- " ``. The only other difference is the padding; `"   "` instead of `"|  "`. So why don't left nodes need the "branches"? Well, you can think of it as the *behind* the right nodes (padding is appended; on the left) going to the left nodes below. You need the padding behind the right to connect the left node/subtree to the parent node. There is nothing behind the left side of a tree, except possibly the parent tree. Which brings me to my last point; every subtree, represented as a list of lines in the `prettyprint_helper` function, gets an additional level of padding every parent tree up. I think it's best illustrated with an example.

---

In creating the tree above (note, I don't know exactly the execution order, especially with lazy evaluation, but this is just to help visualize why it works):

Let's say we recurse down to `10`. Well the subtree on the left and the subtree on the right is empty, so `prettyprint_helper (Branch Leaf 10 Leaf)` returns `["10"]`.

Now we're up to `9`. It's subtree is: `"9" : ([] ++ ((pad "+- " "|  ") [10]))` (no left side), or `"9" : ["+- 10"]`, or:

```
9
+- 10
```

Now we're up to `8`. `((pad "+- " "|   ") (prettyprint_helper right))` creates:

```
+- 9
|  +- 10
```

You can trace it yourself but the left side is:

```
6
+- 7
`- 5
```

Which pads to (first element `` "`- " ``, rest `"   "`):

```
`- 6
   +- 7
   `- 5
```

So altogether for 8, which is the left side appended to the right side, we have:

```
8
+- 9
|  +- 10
`- 6
   +- 7
   `- 5
```

If we go one step up, this `8` subtree is padded for the `4` tree, and again you can trace through the other side to verify it works. You get

```
+- 8
|  +- 9
|  |  +- 10
|  `- 6
|     +- 7
|     `- 5
```

And the final result is as above. Remember, throughout this process the tree is represented as a list of lines. Only at the very end does it get put together with `unlines`. Perhaps my drawings are misleading because it may look like subtrees are being passed around as multiline strings. Once you understand this, it is very easy to add the extra branch (`"|"`) between the left and right nodes like in `Data.Tree`'s `drawTree` function. I'll let you figure it out :)

My apologies if this excessive; it was quite difficult for me to understand from the source as a beginner, and this was a big jump for me. I hope it helps someone else trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another implementation:

[video with explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ud-1Z0hBlB8&feature=youtu.be)

```
───"a"
    └──"b"
        └──"c"
            |                   ┌──"g"
            |               ┌──"c"
            |               |   └──"f"
            |           ┌──"a"
            |           |   |   ┌──"e"
            |           |   └──"b"
            |           |       └──"d"
            |       ┌──"x"
            |       |   |       ┌──"g"
            |       |   |   ┌──"c"
            |       |   |   |   └──"f"
            |       |   └──"a"
            |       |       |   ┌──"e"
            |       |       └──"b"
            |       |           └──"d"
            |   ┌──"f"
            └──"d"


import Data.List
data Btree a = Empty | Node a (Btree a) (Btree a) deriving Show
tr_l = Node "b" (Node "d" Empty Empty) (Node "e" Empty Empty)
tr_r = Node "c" (Node "f" Empty Empty) (Node "g" Empty Empty)
tr = Node "a" tr_l tr_r :: Btree String
tx = Node "x" tr tr

trr = Node "a" (Node "b" (Node "c" (Node "d" Empty (Node "f" Empty tx)) Empty) Empty) Empty:: Btree String

data ParentDir = PLeft | PRight | NoParent deriving (Show,Eq)
type ParentPos = Int
type Level = Int

dline = '|'
factor = 4

m c1 c2 = if c1 == dline then c1 else c2
zipWith' f xs [] = xs
zipWith' f [] xs = xs
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys

build_line pd a pp level = foldl (zipWith' m) "" (((++"|").(flip replicate ' ') <$> (factor*) <$> pp)++[(replicate (factor*level) ' ')++cn++show a])
                           where cn = case pd of PLeft -> "└──"
                                                 PRight -> "┌──"
                                                 NoParent -> "───"

tprint :: Show a => ParentDir -> [ParentPos] -> Level -> Btree a -> [String]
tprint _ _ _ Empty = []
tprint pd pp level (Node a l r) = tprint PRight new_pp_r (level+1) r ++
                                  [build_line pd a pp level] ++
                                  tprint PLeft new_pp_l (level+1) l
                                  where new_pp_r = case pd of PRight -> pp
                                                              PLeft -> pp++[level]
                                                              NoParent -> pp
                                        new_pp_l = case pd of PRight -> pp++[level]
                                                              PLeft -> pp
                                                              NoParent -> pp

printt t = putStr $ (intercalate "\r\n" (tprint NoParent [] 0 t))++"\r\n"
```