# Print out a Binary Tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

This is my Guidline:

```
data BinTree α = Empty
   | Node (BinTree α) α (BinTree α)
     deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now i want to create a function:

```
levels :: BinTree a -> [[a]]
```

This should print out a Binary Tree in a list, but each level in its own. For Example: `[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6,7]]` or

```
[1]
[2,3]
[4,5,6,7]
```

...

I defined the `roots` and `childs`:

```
roots ts = [ a | Node _ a _ <- ts ]
childs ts = [ t | Node l _ r <- ts, t <- [l, r] ]
```

and a traverse function which gets a list of subtree and its node.

```
traverse' :: [BinTree α] -> [α]
traverse' [] = []
traverse' ts = roots ts ++ traverse' (childs ts)

levels :: BinTree α -> [α]
levels t = traverse [t]
```

But thats not what I really wanted. Does someone has an idea.

Comment: Try writing `f :: BinTree a -> [[a]]`, which converts a binary tree to a list of lists, in which the first list contains the root, the second list the childs, the next the grandchilds and so on. You're almost done after that.

Comment: Otherwise have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556469/nicely-printing-showing-a-binary-tree-in-haskell?rq=1) question, it might help with designing the function.

Comment: Think about how you would express levels of a node in terms of the levels of the left and right child nodes. Have you been introduced to the `zip` function?

Comment: `levels ts = roots ts : levels (childs ts)`

Comment: My problem is, that i don't know how i could print it out as above mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
f Empty = []
f (Node l v r) = case (f l, f r) of
                   ((x:xs),(y:ys)) -> [[v],x++y] ++ (zipWith (++) xs ys)
                   ([],[])         -> [[v]]
                    ......
```

Complete the patterns. (You can test this with a complete tree to be sure it's a good start).